# OpenShift Web UI on upstream k8s

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

Recently I discovered, that is possible to run OpenShift Web UI on upstream k8s

Is this possible? I understand that projects are defacto namespaces, but is there any fallback/callback to native k8s API ? ( at least routes will not definetily work ... )

**For example:**

1. https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager#user-interface
2. https://github.com/kubevirt/web-ui#native-kubernetes
3. https://github.com/openshift/console#native-kubernetes

No mention about upstream k8s here:

**console-operator:**  https://github.com/openshift/console-operator ( seems its > 4.X version )

Registries:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin-console-operator/tags
- https://quay.io/repository/openshift/origin-console-operator?tab=tags

**standalone:** https://github.com/openshift/console  ( version >= 3.X )

Registries:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin-console/tags
- https://quay.io/repository/openshift/origin-console?tab=tags

Can anyone tell me more?

Or did anyone succeced with openshift ui on upstream k8s?

P.S. I dont want to deploy openshift/okd solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [openshift/console](https://github.com/openshift/console#native-kubernetes) repo has a section on deploying within upstream kubernetes. The console pods can be deployed using the [openshift/console-operator](https://github.com/openshift/console-operator) Kubernetes operator, but the documentation for the implementation appears to say that this operator is OpenShift > 4.0 specific.